# How can I pass a binding expression as text into a directive isolation scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a custom directive similar to a list-box. This is my directive definition:

```
angular.module('Utilities')
    .directive('searchList', [
        function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: '/app/scripts/Utilities/search/search.html',
                controller: 'SearchCtrl',
                scope: {
                    itemsSource: '=',
                    itemTemplate: '@',
                    filterText: '=?',
                    selectedItem: '=?',
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Here's how I want to use it in my view:

```
<search-list items-source="productsSource" 
             item-template="{{item.Name}} Selling for: {{item.Price}}"
             selected-item="selectedProduct" />
```

Both `productsSource` and `selectedProduct` come from the view's scope (they work fine). I want `item-template` to be taken straight up as text (there is no item object in the scope used by my view).

Inside `SearchCtrl` I obtain the items to show in my search-list, and then I want to apply that `item-template` to each item (through the use of the `$compile` service).

The problem is that inside `SearchCtrl` `$scope.itemTemplate` is equal to `Selling for:` (the `{{}}` syntax was resolved, not passed as text)

tl;dr

My search.html template looks like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in itemsDataSource" ng-class-odd="'oddRow'" ng-class-even="'evenRow'">
    <div class="searchResultsItem" ng-click="onItemSelected(item)">
        <span compile="internalItemTemplate"></span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Since `itemTemplate` is one-way binding, the `SearchCtrl` will reassign it to `internalItemTemplate`.

```
    if (typeof $scope.itemTemplate === 'undefined') {
        $scope.internalItemTemplate = '{{item}}';
    } else {
        $scope.internalItemTemplate = $scope.itemTemplate;
    }
```

The compile directive on the span tag was borrowed from: [Angular Docs for $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

It looks like this:

```
angular.module('Utilities')
    .directive('compile', ['$compile',
        function ($compile) {
            // directive factory creates a link function
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(
                  function (scope) {
                      // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
                      return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
                  },
                  function (value) {
                      // when the 'compile' expression changes
                      // assign it into the current DOM
                      element.html(value);

                      // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
                      // scope.
                      // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
                      // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
                      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                  }
                );
            };
        }
    ]);
```

If I hard-code  `$scope.internalItemTemplate` in `SearchCtrl` to be `'{{item.Name}} Selling for: {{item.Price}}'`, than it works.

How do I get my directive to allow the passing of `{{}}` without trying to resolve it?

Comment: Surround with single quotes

Comment: Quotes don't seem to work. It passes the quotes but still tries to resolve the binding expression contained within. I end up with: `' Selling for: '`

Answer (score 1):

Changing the scope type from `@` to `=` and then surrounding it in quotes worked.

The directive would look like this:

```
angular.module('Utilities')
    .directive('searchList', [
        function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: '/app/scripts/Utilities/search/search.html',
                controller: 'SearchCtrl',
                scope: {
                    itemsSource: '=',
                    itemTemplate: '=',
                    filterText: '=?',
                    selectedItem: '=?',
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

and the view would look like this:

```
<search-list items-source="productsSource" 
             item-template="'{{item.Name}} Selling for: {{item.Price}}'"
             selected-item="selectedProduct" />
```